# Why ibus-avro works only with Unity of ubuntu 16.04 LTS but not with GNome or Mint?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, ibus

I have installed ibus-avro in Ubuntu 16.04. I was using GNOME desktop and ibus-avro was not available there. It was also not available on MINT (cinnamon). Luckily I found it is working with Unity desktop. However ibus-avro was working earlier with all the desktop environments of Ubuntu 14.04.
Now I like to use ibus-avro in my GNOME environment of UBUNTU 16.06.

Comment: See this https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/102

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to GNOME or MINT.